EF Core with XUnit "The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken."
When I run multiple unit tests that use the same API, I am randomly getting this error:

The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken.

Here are the exception details. I am not using any transactions.

at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.Promote()
at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)
at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)

This is my code:
var framework = await _dbContext.FrameworkContexts
                                .Where(x => x.FrameworkContextId == frameworkId)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
return framework;

I have tried different solutions but none of them worked I am using scoped DI for repositories.

Many unit test frameworks will run tests in parallel so depending on how your code under test is structured and how the DbContext is injected/scoped that could lead to issues. Normally unit tests would not be talking to a DbContext they would be using a Mock of the DbSets or a thin Repository abstraction that could serve stub data. For more integration-type tests against a database, ensure either that the tests are run sequentially or that dependencies are isolated in a way that each test is given its own scoped DbContext instance.
